# Settings > Location and Security > Screen unlock . Source?

Tags: android

I want to use a lock settings for my app that looks like this settings "Settings > Location and Security > Screen unlock" but i don't have any idea how where to find source code for this part of android (2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, please pull Android source to your machine: http://source.android.com/
And then, look for package: `com.android.settings`. Everything of `Settings` application is there for you.